# Adding Stamp/Watermark/Content over PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am using following code:

```
PdfReader PDFReader = new PdfReader("C:\\file.pdf");

FileStream Stream = new FileStream("C:\\new.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

PdfStamper PDFStamper = new PdfStamper(PDFReader, Stream);

for (int iCount = 0; iCount < PDFStamper.Reader.NumberOfPages; iCount++)
{
    PdfContentByte PDFData = PDFStamper.GetOverContent(iCount + 1);
    BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    PDFData.BeginText();
    PDFData.SetColorFill(CMYKColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
    PDFData.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 80);
    PDFData.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "SAMPLE DOCUMENT", 300, 400, 45);
    PDFData.EndText();
}

Stream.Close();
PDFReader.Close();
PDFStamper.Close();
```

But `PDFStamper.Close();` throws error. Also, I am not sure whether to call `PDFReader.Close();` before or after `PDFStamper.Close();`

And watermark is not added in PDF file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your order of `Close` calls is all wrong:

```
Stream.Close();
PDFReader.Close();
PDFStamper.Close();
```

In particular the `PDFStamper` requires both the `PDFReader` and the `Stream` to still be open when it is getting closed.

Furthermore, unless an exception is thrown, the `Stream` automatically is closed during `PDFStamper.Close()`.

Thus, use

```
PDFStamper.Close();
PDFReader.Close();
```

instead.

If you want to make sure that the `Stream` is getting closed in case of an exception, use a `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine now. But one question, I want my text to appera inside the page, it is not covering the whole page, sometimes it is smaller than the page and sometimes larger.

Comment: You get this behavior because you are using hard coded coordinates (`x = 300` and `y = 400`). You should calculate the offset. See for instance [How to add an image watermark to a PDF file?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-add-image-watermark-pdf-file) In your case, you also want to check `pagesize.getRight()` and `pagesize.getTop()` to find out if your watermark exceeds the available space. See also [How to position text relative to page?](http://itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page) Those are Java examples. You'll have to make minimal changes to make this work in iTextSharp

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Hi Bruno Lowagie, thanks for the reply. I am honored to speak to you. I will try to set the coordinates. I am trying to put a watermark in diagonal way as "Sample Document" in the PDF file. I am sure you must have seen such in many documents. I want to have it as exactly starting from bottom left to top right of the page irrespective of page coordinates etc. So, I will try to use some maths to get. and will look into the link that you gave. Thanks.

Comment: @ComputerUser *you also want to check `pagesize.getRight()` and `pagesize.getTop()` to find out if your watermark exceeds the available space.* - And also check `pagesize.Left` and `pagesize.Bottom`: They don't need to be `0` (even if they often are)!

Comment: Is pagesize.getTop(0) same as pagesize.Top? and similarly for other coordinates like pagesize.getLeft(0) and pagesize.Left?

Comment: *Is pagesize.getTop(0) same as pagesize.Top? and similarly for other coordinates like pagesize.getLeft(0) and pagesize.Left?* - yes. The method `GetTop(float)` allows you to automatically have a `margin` value applied to the border, and for a margin of `0` you get the original border.

Comment: @mkl, one more question, if I may, is there any way to find out if the text inserted/overlaid is going to exceed the page size? for example, if the page size is small and I hard code font size to like 40, it may happen that the text exceeds the size if page size is smaller than a certain size that will fit the text overlaid. So, is there any way to determine if my text will fit or not for certain font size?

Comment: That actually exceeds the bounds of a comment; thus, it is good you made this a stackoverflow question in its own right. I'll look into this later.

Comment: @mkl please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34470511/how-to-know-if-text-exceeds-the-fill-box-in-itextsharp